# PHP readfile not working correctly with Safari

Tags: php, audio, safari, http-headers, readfile

I am loading an mp3 into an html `<audio>` tag. The source of that tag is really a php script which returns a song that is not hosted in the public directory.

Omitting most of validation and other code, the headers used to output the mp3 are:

```
    header( 'Content-type: {$mime_type}' );
    header( 'Content-length: ' . filesize( $file ));
    header( 'Content-Disposition: inline;filename="'.$filename.'"' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
    header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
    header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
    header( 'Expires: 0');


    readfile( $file );
```

This works on Firefox, Chrome (and mobile), Edge (and mobile) and Opera. However I can't seem to get Safari to use the generated url as an audio source. In fact, no audio source appears in the DOM after the page has rendered:

[image]

The url might look like, `www.website.com/song.php?sid=234234234234`

I have tried tweaking this file plenty of times but can't see to figure out why this is happening on Safari. My intuition is the way the browser deals with mp3s and the like, which should be dealt with in the header.

Any guidance, hints or help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

update:
Added the network, shows that it loads the mp3 but then the second request doesn't?
[image: Description]

**response headers:**

```
Name    Value
Server  Apache
Content-Type    audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3
Date    Wed, 28 Dec 2016 17:24:48 GMT
Cache-Control   no-cache
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.29
Content-Disposition inline;filename="148_2793d1c49976a3689147634359577ec1aa5619f1.mp3"
Content-Length  834312
Expires 0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Transfer-Encoding   binary
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Pragma  no-cache
```

Comment: If you don't see the `src` attribute in the audio tag, the problem is in the HTML, not the PHP script. It's never calling the PHP script in the first place.

Comment: Check the header response...because "header( 'Content-type: {$mime_type}' );" is not replacing the value, since single quote doesn't works in php for replacing values in vars if I'm not wrong even with "{ }". Try to change it to header( 'Content-type: '.$mime_type}' ); if doesn't works, then, please add the network headers to your question (correct me if I'm wrong with something :) )

Comment: @Asfo great suggestion, but didn't work. Here are the network headers:

http://i.imgur.com/9xsiyqx.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the Multiple ranges header, because it's a partial content: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2

```
header("Accept-Ranges: 0-filesize( $file )");
```

EDIT

Take a look here:
http://www.techstruggles.com/mp3-streaming-for-apple-iphone-with-php-readfile-file_get_contents-fail/

You need to define some headers for safari, even for the mobile version.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( I've updated the post to include the network screen shot. But if you were interested in debugging it locally (safari vs chrome) an example is here https://leerecs.com/library/index.php?action=recent

Comment: I think you're right with accept-ranges, but I just haven't been able to get it to work yet. Hmmm.  Do you think my header has something excessive in it?

Comment: I can't see the response headers. Anyway, why on the request headers the Range header has "0-1"? The filesize is 1byte?

Comment: The link you posted had a tremendous library for this. It works now, I can't thank you enough -- I don't think I would have figured it out. Cheers.

Comment: Using just `header("Accept-Ranges: 0-filesize( $file )");` didn't work for me (in iOS safari) but the link helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue sometime ago, sorry if I don't remember correctly how I fixed that, but is a header issue (its the main part I can remember, and I don't use comments for adding the answer because its too long)

Try with this..

```
  header( 'Accept-Ranges: bytes'); 
  header("Pragma: public");
  header("Expires: 0");
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');      
  header('Content-Length: '.$fsize);
  header('Content-Type: audio/'.$t);
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
  header('Content-Range: bytes 0-'.$shortlen.'/'.$fsize); 
  header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
  header('Etag: '.$etag);
```

Where:

```
  $filename = "myaudio.mp3";
  $path = 'music/'.$filename;
  $fsize = filesize($path);
  $shortlen = $fsize - 1;

  $fp = fopen($path, 'r');
  $etag = md5(serialize(fstat($fp)));
  fclose($fp);
  $t = "mpeg";
```

Hope this helps, but the 2 main headers you need is "Etag" and "Accept-Ranges" if I'm not wrong.